Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\binom{n}{x}dx$.
Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\binom{n}{x}dx$.
This question came in Cambridge Integration Bee and I have no clue what to do in this.
I rewrote $\binom{n}{x}$ as $\frac{n!}{{x!}{(n-x)!}}$ but I don't know how to integrate those factorials. Also what to do if $n$ isn't an integer as no information regarding it is given?

I think what is meant is $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(n-x+1)}dx $$ since $k!=\Gamma(k+1)$ and $\binom{n}{x}=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$.

P.S. And the answer is probably $2^n$....

@vanderWolf what should I do after gamma function?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad If $n$ is an integer, you can use the identities $\Gamma (x+1)=x\Gamma (x)$ and $\Gamma (x)\Gamma (1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi x}$

@Cyankite Hey how did you arrive at the last identity...ive never heard of it

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I thought it was a well-known reflection formula.... Its proof is not very simple

@Cyankite well known...maybe for you mavens but I'm a noob..I never heard of this

Since  $$\dbinom {n}{x}=\dbinom{n-1}{x}+ \dbinom{n-1}{x-1}$$
$$I_n:= \int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \dbinom{n}{x}dx= \color{red}{\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \dbinom{n-1}{x}dx}+ \color{blue}{\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \dbinom{n-1}{x-1}dx}$$
And by using a substitution  $x=t-1$ then replacing $t$ with $x$ one gets
$$I_{n-1}= \color{red}{\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \dbinom{n-1}{x}dx}= \color{blue}{\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \dbinom{n-1}{x-1}dx}$$
then $I_n = 2I_{n-1}$ so $I_n= 2^n I_0 $
$$I_0= \int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \dbinom{0}{x}dx= \int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \frac{1}{(x)!(-x)!}dx$$

$$\Gamma(1+x)=x!$$
$$\Gamma(x) \Gamma(1-x) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$$

$$I_0 =\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}dx= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \frac{\sin( x)}{x}dx $$
and since $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \frac{\sin( x)}{x}dx = \pi$ so $I_0 =1 $ and $I_n = 2^n $

Pls prove that formula of pi/sin(pi x)... How did that come up??

Nice answer. What if $n$ is not an integer?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad This is a known formula there are may different to prove this see this for a proof

@Cyankite I don't think a closed form exists if $n$ is not an integer.

This is more than elegant ! (+1) for sure. The formula seems to work for non integer values of $n$.

This reasoning seems a bit like a vacuous truth. The first equation is only true for integer $x$ and $n$, and when we assume that this binomial coefficient is actually a beta function $${n \choose x} = \frac{1}{(n+1)B(n-k+1,k+1)}$$ then it is also true for any $k>0$. But what about the negative numbers? The beta function can be extended to negative numbers but do all derived properties still hold?

You get the result from one of the Ramanujan's Papers, formula 1.2, by setting $n=0$, $\alpha=0$, $\beta=n+2$, and using the fact that
$$
\binom{n}{x}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n-x+1)\Gamma(x+1)} 
$$
so that
\begin{align*}
\int \binom{n}{x} dx &=\int \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+2-y)\Gamma(y)}  dy\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\int \frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(n+2-y)\Gamma(y)}  dy\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\int \frac{dy}{\mathrm{B}(n+2-y,y)}.
\end{align*}

How to integrate that beta-function integral? And your link is not available to me(HTTP ERROR 502)

@Cyankite, could you check now for it seems to work (at least for me)?

@Cyankite, it's a "non-secure" connection, you should let your browser open it.

@vanderWolf It is OK now:)

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{n \choose x}\dd x} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\pars{1 + \expo{\ic\phi}}^{n} \over \expo{\ic x\phi}}{\dd\phi \over 2\pi}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\pars{1 + \expo{\ic\phi}}^{n}\,\
\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic\phi x}\,
{\dd x \over 2\pi}}^{\ds{\delta\pars{\phi}}}}\,\
\,\dd\phi = \pars{1 + \expo{\ic 0}}^{n} = \bbx{\color{#44f}{2^{n}}} \\ &
\end{align}

Can you explain the formula for $\binom nx$?

@user See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorychev_method

@user170231 I know this method being applied to integer $x$. Nothing else can be found in the reference you gave. So some additional work / explanation is needed.

@user Please take a look at https://www.instagram.com/p/Cyo5SY3yXlP/?igsh=MXg3M242dmh6eGF3aA==

@Dqrksun I would like to see a proof of the relation, unless it is the definition of $\binom nx$.

It would be useful to have a proof or verification of the result of this formal argument.

@user What do you mean? The proof is in the instagram post

Generally, $$\binom{y}{x}=\frac{e^{i\pi x}}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_R}\frac{(1-z)^y}{z^{x+1}}, dz-\frac{\sin \pi x}{x}\int_0^{1-R}(1-t)^{-x-1}t^y, dt$$
where $C_R$ denotes the circle with radius $R$ on the complex plane centered at $0$

@Dqrksun I see no proof. Please start with definition of $\binom yx$.

@user What do you mean you see no proof? The derivation is in the second and the third slide. If you want to start from the definition of $\binom{y}{x}$, then start from the $4-$th line of third slide and read backwards to the start of second slide

@Dqrksun So far I did not see the second and the third slide. It's nice that now you've mentioned it.

@user It might be that you did not log in.

@Dqrksun I have no Instagram login and also do not have an intention to have it.
